# Solving Initial Value Problems 2nd Order DEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

$$3(y-1)^2 = y''$$ where $y(0) = 3$, $y'(0) = 4$ and we assume $y \neq 1$.

I know how to solve IVPs in when the 2nd order DE is in the form:

$$p(x)y'' + q(x)y' + g(x)y = 0,$$

however, I think this problem shows a non-linear 2nd order DE based on the "vertex" form of $y$ which is $(y-1)^2$.

I tried substitution with $v = y'$ and expanding the squared expression, but it's getting me no where.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this is solvable? I was under the impression that most non-linear DE's are not solvable.

Comment: Oh!! I forgot to add the initial conditions. y(0) = 3 and y'(0) = 4. Also assume that y =/= 1.

Comment: @graydad: That's a correct impression. If one makes a change of variables to the simpler looking ODE $z''=z^2$, then WA reports an answer in terms of the Weierstrass-$\mathcal{P}$ function. (Which is one of the ways of defining that function, in fact...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the way to solve this is to multiply both sides by $y'$

$$3(y-1)^2y'=y'y''$$
$$(y-1)^3=\frac12(y')^2+C$$
$$(3-1)^3=\frac12(4)^2+C,C=0$$
$$y'=\sqrt2(y-1)^{3/2}$$
$$(y-1)^{-3/2}dy=\sqrt2dt$$
$$-\frac2{\sqrt{y-1}}=\sqrt2t+C$$
$$-\frac2{\sqrt{3-1}}=C, C=-\sqrt2$$
$$\sqrt{y-1}=-\frac2{\sqrt2t-\sqrt2}$$
$$y-1=\frac2{t^2-2t+1}$$
$$y=1+\frac2{t^2-2t+1}$$

Comment: How'd you get from 3(y−1)^2y′=y′y″ to (y−1)^3=1/2(y′)^2+C (the first step) and getting rid of the y''.

Comment: @Wade Integrating both sides.

Comment: @Wade Corrected mistakes from the second integration.  Plugging this into the DE gives $\frac{12}{(t-1)^4}$ on both sides.